# Is it a good idea to have final static constant in Java Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, jackson

I have a Java servlet, where I want to use the [Jackson JSON parser](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

Rather than instantiate it multiple times (I use it in different functions in the servlet), is it safe to declare it as a 'static final' and reuse the 'ObjectMapper' across different methods in the same servlet?

Here's an example of how I currently have it:

```
public class ServiceExample extends HttpServlet {

  private final static ObjectMapper jsonHelper = new ObjectMapper();

  public void doSomething() {
    jsonHelper.writeValueAsString(new SomeObject());
  }

  public void doSomethingElse() {
    jsonHelper.writeValueAsString(new SomeOtherObject());
  }
}
```

I thought I read somewhere that this was okay, but I wanted to double check.

**Edit**

[According to this, it is thread-safe so long as it's configured before it's used.](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQThreadSafety)

Thanks.

Comment: Slight expansion on Dave Newtons comment.  It is only good to have a final static ObjectMapper in your servlet if the ObjectMapper class is thread-safe.  If ObjectMapper is not thread-safe, they you want to create a new ObjectMapper for each request.

Comment: Thanks both.  I updated the post... looks like `ObjectMapper` is thread safe so long as it's configured before it's used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So then you configure it in a static initializer method inside your class. Then it should not be an issue.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't need to configure it (the default configuration works for how I need it), but if I did need to, I now see that's how I'd want to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Servlets are normally singletons anyhow, so it wouldn't make any difference if you had it configured as:

```
public class ServiceExample extends HttpServlet {

  private final ObjectMapper jsonHelper = new ObjectMapper();

}
```

The cavet to this is if you have multiple `<servlet>` entries for the same servlet class in web.xml will result in one instance of the servlet for each `<servlet>` element.

The important thing to figure out is whether or not the `ObjectMapper` from jackson is threadsafe.

Comment: I see.  So `static` doesn't matter since they're usually singletons, but final does.  I'm actually using Google App Engine, so I wasn't sure if there might be more to it (since their services will scale).  On reading the Jackson javadocs, it sounds like `ObjectMapper` is threadsafe.  Thanks for the additional insight.

Comment: the final doesn't actually matter too much in this case (for thread safety) but does put a nice clear sign post out that this field won't change in the life of the Servlet. On App Engine each instance is actually a new JVM (on another server) so you will get a whole new instance of your application.